# Django How to save JSON data outside a view in a session and retrieve the saved data inside the view?

Tags: django

I have JSON data which I want to store uniquely for each user inside a session.

The problem is, the module which generates the JSON data is async is outside the Django view because it is very resource demanding. I want the JSON data this separate module generates to be stored in a session so that the data is unique for each user.

I have tried the following outside my view module:

```
from django.contrib.sessions.backends.db import SessionStore
s = SessionStore()
s['json_data'] = json_var
s.save()
```

But when I try to read the saved session data back inside a view, it loads nothing e.g. it doesn't go inside if statement:

```
    if 'json_data' in request.session:
        json_var = request.session['json_data']
```

Is there an elegant way to do this?

Comment: why store it in session? I would recommend using either DB/models to store it, or use Redis(or memory based data storage) to store this information

Comment: @ruddra thank you for your reply. I want to use the session because the JSON data is used for a very temporary period of time, and its purpose is to just display results on the UI. If I use like DB, how will I be able to identify which user has sent request?

Comment: How do you determine it current implementation?

Comment: @ruddra I actually had made a very blunt attempt to save the JSON data in files but the saved files are same for each user. So to overcome this challenge, I am trying to somehow use sessions.

Comment: If it is all the same for all users then using session may not be a good idea.

Comment: @ruddra my system is like a search engine, it returns JSON results according to the issued user query. I want the system to consider that JSON results should be sent to the user according to their issued query.